# jquery - Looking for same content

Tags: jquery, html, select, addclass

i've trying getting this working with selectors, while, for, etc but i'm not getting close that in what want.

```
<div class="product">
<div class="id">569865974598</div>
<div class="name">Ati Radeon Sapphire Hd 6850</div>
<div class="time">2013-02-14 03:13:33</div>
</div>

<div class="product">
<div class="id">654654654987</div>
<div class="name">Nvidia Geforce 9500gt</div>
<div class="time">2013-02-14 00:36:13</div>
</div>

<div class="product">
<div class="id">2561564898789</div>
<div class="name">Ati Radeon Sapphire Hd 6850</div>
<div class="time">2013-02-14 00:36:13</div>
</div>
```

Expected(encapsulate products with same time)

```
<div id="same">
    <div class="product">
    <div class="id">569865974598</div>
    <div class="name">Ati Radeon Sapphire Hd 6850</div>
    <div class="time">2013-02-14 03:13:33</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="same">
    <div class="product">
    <div class="id">654654654987</div>
    <div class="name">Nvidia Geforce 9500gt</div>
    <div class="time">2013-02-14 00:36:13</div>
    </div>

    <div class="product">
    <div class="id">2561564898789</div>
    <div class="name">Ati Radeon Sapphire Hd 6850</div>
    <div class="time">2013-02-14 00:36:13</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The id selector is used to specify a style for a single, unique element. This allows you to set a particular style for many HTML elements with the same class.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have the first HTML code and you want sort it to the second HTML code? Or the first HTML code is what you are generating and it is not what you want?

Comment: how are you generating your HTML ?

Comment: The first html code is generating by other function and i want to fits like the second html code, so can make a style with css(). Sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.product').each(function(){
        // generate div id based on time e.g. 2013-02-14 00:36:13 -> id=20130214003613
        var id = $(this).find('.time').html().replace(/[\s-:]/g,"");

        var sameElement = $('#' + id);

        if(sameElement.length == 0){
            $('body').append('<div id=' + id + '></div>');
            sameElement = $('#' + id);
        }
        $(this).appendTo(sameElement);
    });

});
```

Note: Having multiple div elements with same id is not correct, this is why instead of proposed by you id='same' there is generated id based on time

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zt38S/

Comment: Yes this did the ninja trick, there was a problem because this data is generated through ajax(json), so i used ajaxComplete().Now can i continue thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of, don't use the same id on several elements, id must be unique in HTML,
instead use for example the class attribute.

This code will first find all unique times, and then wrap all time groups in divs with the class 'same'.

Available on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RA9eb/

```
(function () {
    var uniqueTimes = $.unique($('.product').map(function() {
        return $(this).find('.time').text();
    })).get();

    $.each(uniqueTimes, function (i, time) {
        $('.product').filter(function () {
            return $(this).find('.time').text() == time;
        }).wrapAll($('<div />').addClass('same'));
    });
})();
```